# What is the right package to get 32bit include header sys/sysinfo.h on 64bit Debian Buster?

Tags: apt

I want to get this header. I ran this command:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

But I don't know if I should pick **linux-libc-dev:i386** or a **linux header** package?

I tried linux-libc-dev:i386 but gcc does not find the header when compiling using -m32.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `gcc -m32` to work, you need to install `gcc-multilib` and `libc6-dev:i386`.

Another way to build 32-bit x86 programs on Debian is to use the cross-compilers: install `gcc-i686-linux-gnu`, then use `i686-linux-gnu-gcc`.

Comment: Thank you. For those who want to know it also requires package **gcc-multilib**.